# What is the right way to populate a ListView with data fetched from the internet on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, web, background

I know this is kind of a theoretical question, but the thing is I'm starting on Android, I already got the basics, and know I want build a small App by myself, but I want it done *the right way*.

I have a ***ListView*** that displays the data in a ***SQLite DB***. And that data is updated from the web every time I start the app and also every time I return to this ***Activity*** with a ***ListView*** in it. Also the data it's also re-updated (but just for one object instead of all that are collected in the ListView) when I enter a ***DetailView*** of that object I choose from the ***ListView***.

Now, I believe I should use an **Intent** or an **IntentService** (which is called asyncronously already by default in Android) to fetch the data in the background:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
  public DownloadService() {
    super("DownloadService");
  }

  // Will be called asynchronously be Android
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
...
```

But all the tutorials I see actually use an **Activity** and then call and some class extending ***AsyncTask***:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...
// DownloadData AsyncTask
    private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
...
```

Perhaps I should use even a different method, but I don't really need to be pointed to a tutorial, I just need a more experienced Android programmer to tell me how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that should be Async type tasks, a good design that similar to what you are trying to accomplish at [Marakana Yamba Project](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf7z_mrce00&list=PL3710DA3298744F4A).  The videos have a lot of dead space, so I would look for the ones that talk about the design, it will give you the correct design method.  The points that will be brought out there are, the async DownloadData task that you already have and then you should look for the one on the Content Provider.  Your DownloadData will handle efficient downloads from the Internet, as the radio loves your battery.  The Content Provider will work kinda the same way, but in feeding data to the UI activity of your app.  The basic recommended type of design.

Hope this helps.